# Hess's Law and ΔH

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, heat, combustion

Target equation: $\ce{Mg(s) + 1/2 O2 -> MgO(s)}$

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{MgO(s) + 2 HCl(aq) &-> MgCl2(aq) + H2O(l)} &\quad ΔH &= \pu{-1300 kJ} \tag{1}\\  
\ce{Mg(s) + 2 HCl(aq) &-> MgCl2(aq) + H2(g)} &\quad ΔH &= \pu{-602 kJ} \tag{2}\\
\ce{H2(g) + 1/2 O2 &-> H2O(l)} &\quad ΔH &= \pu{-286 kJ} \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

The target equation should have a negative $ΔH$ meaning that it's exothermic, but when I add it up, $ΔH$ ends up being positive. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: If you are calculating $ΔΗ$ as $(2) + (3) - (1)$, then it looks correct, however, you are right, it should be negative. Is there a typo for $ΔΗ_1?$ It looks way to high: $\pu{-130 kJ mol-1}$ would make more sense than $\pu{-1300 kJ mol-1}$ IMO (I assume molar enthalpy based on the value for (3)).

Comment: I got 1300 kJ mol−1 by taking 3.34 kJ (the q value for energy absorbed by HCl) and the number of mols of MgO used, 0.00257 mol, and dividing 3.34 by 0.00257. One thing I forgot to mention is that this is a lab. Is there anything in the q = mcΔT calculation for HCl that I messed up on?

Comment: It's hard to tell, but most likely yes, enthalpy of the first reaction has been determined incorrectly. You probably should [edit] in more details as to how it was obtained, as well as the value you expect and why (I already [commented on that](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/123850/hesss-law-and-%ce%94h#comment236647_123853)).

Comment: I agreed with @andselisk. I already give an answer, but I'm looking at where you have made mistake, as a part of following andselisk's suggestions. I assumed you made mistake on amount of $\ce{Mg}$ you have used. It should be $\pu{\approx 0.025 mol}$, if you have used $\pu{\approx 1 g}$ of $\ce{Mg}$. So please edit your post to include all these details.

Answer (score 1):

Your target equation is: $\ce{Mg(s) + 1/2O2 -> MgO(s)}$. You have given following set of equations to get your target's enthalpy of formation:
$$\ce{MgO(s) + 2HCl(aq) -> MgCl2(aq) + H2O(l)} \quad ΔH = \pu{-1300 kJ} \tag {1}$$  $$\ce{Mg(s) + 2HCl(aq) -> MgCl2(aq) + H2(g)} \quad ΔH = \pu{-602 kJ} \tag {2}$$
$$\ce{H2(g) + 1/2O2 -> H2O(l)} \quad ΔH = \pu{-286 kJ} \tag {3}$$

Yet, if you added equations $(1)$ through $(3)$, you won't get your target equation because you have set equation $(1)$ in opposite direction so that $\ce{MgO}$ would ends up in reactant side (LHS). What you should have done is reverse that reaction. The reverse of Equation $(1)$ has identical $\Delta H$ but with opposite sign:

$$\ce{MgCl2(aq) + H2O(l) -> MgO(s) + 2HCl(aq)} \quad ΔH = \pu{+1300 kJ} \tag {4}$$

Now you can add equations $(2)$ through $(4)$, and you should get a negative $ΔH$ for your target equation (meaning the reaction is exothermic, and given $\Delta H^\circ_f$ for $\ce{MgO}$ is $\pu{−601.6 kJ/mol}$ according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_formation)). However, your given $\Delta H$ values are seemingly incorrect and I leave you to find the correct values (Note: The given $\Delta H^\circ_f$ for water is acceptable).

**Late edition:** According to OP's late comment to andselisk's suggestion on first comment, it seems OP has made a mistake on amount of $\ce{MgO}$ calculation, of which OP has used in the calarimetric experiment. It should have been $\pu{\approx 0.025 mol}$, if OP has used $\pu{\approx 1 g}$ of $\ce{MgO}$. Thus, $\Delta H$ for the reaction $\ce{MgO(s) + 2HCl(aq) -> MgCl2(aq) + H2O(l)}$ should have been $\approx \pu{3.34 kJ}/\pu{0.025 mol}= \approx \pu{134 kJ/mol}$. Thus, $\Delta H^\circ_f$ of $\ce{MgO}$ from the experiment is: $\pu{(+134-602-286) kJ/mol}=\pu{-754 kJ/mol}$ (literature value is $\pu{−601.6 kJ/mol}$).

Until the time of this edition, OP has not edited the question. Thus, I assume OP has also calculated the data for the reaction $\ce{Mg(s) + 2HCl(aq) -> MgCl2(aq) + H2(g)}$, actual value of which has been around $\pu{−460 kJ/mol}$. Hence, approximate experimental value for $\Delta H^\circ_f{_\ce{MgO}}$ is: $\pu{(+134-460-286) kJ/mol}=\pu{-612 kJ/mol}$, which is better acceptable value for literature value, $\pu{−601.6 kJ/mol}$.

Comment: As I already mentioned in the comment, the first value for neutralization looks way off. Since you already posted an attempt to answer, probably it would make sense to add that $ΔH_1$ should be approx. double the value of [standard enthalpy of neutralization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_neutralization), $\pu{-57.62 kJ mol-1}.$ That's why I assumed $\pu{-130 kJ mol-1}$. Still it would be nicer if you dig up actual literature values; in the absence of those it's just speculations.

Comment: @ andselisk: Couldn't fond real literature values for them, but approximate values were calculated using standard enthalpies of formation given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_formation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add the three equations ?

By first adding (2) and (3) and then SUBSTRACTING (1), you find Mg + (1/2) O2  -->  MgO.

On the other end, I think some of these numerical values are wrong, because one should obtain -602 kJ/mol, which is the heat of formation of MgO. And the combination of the given values do not yield to this result, by far.

Comment: I got 1300 kJ/mol by calculating q of HCl divided by number of moles of MgO used, which ended being 3.34 kJ divided by 0.00257 mol. This was a lab by the way.